# How we can download a PDF embedded with javascript in a web page

Tags: javascript, pdf

More specifically from "http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in" it is a repository of Thesis. Previously IDM was able to capture all the pdf requests but now some Coding has been changed and its inaccessible now. Upon reaching to the network tab it does show it as a XHR file under pdf.worker.js.

Here is a trial link

http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/displaybitstream?handle=1/5810062295

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the website in question has measures preventing the download. In web, this is mostly a slow-down. If a document is available in The Net for you to view, during viewing the document is on your computer and can be extracted for later use.

One of the simple solutions is to use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/), a command-line tool available in many operating systems and combine that with Google Chrome developer tools. Chrome in Network-tab can output a ready-made curl-command from the PDF-load made in the website to be pasted into a command-prompt.

I reduced the output to bare minimum:

```
curl 'https://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/bitstream/1/5810062295/1/Anil%20Kumar%202601' \
  -X 'POST' \
  -H 'keyname: Akz914723960' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 0' \
  -H 'Type: application/pdf' \
  --output Document.pdf
```

This approach is not generic to all documents in the website, but will download the specified PDF into a file named `Document.pdf` on your own drive. The critical security measure used by the website is the *keyname*-header.

Comment: For any kind of hacking, Windows is not the best platform. Linux or macOS are better suited. The above curl-command does work on my Windows with Cygwin.

Comment: Curl `--output` is documented at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-o. You may specify a directory there also. In the above form, the download is done into the current directory.